# Can't open .exe generated after converting .py to .exe with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm trying to convert a `.py` file to .`exe` using `py2exe`.

I make the setup file with this code (for a simple hello world code):

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

    setup(console=["hello.py"])
```

after writing at cmd:

```
    python setup.py py2exe
```

I get the **build** and **dist** folders.

Inside the **dist** folder, I've the hello.exe file.

***but*** , when I open the `.exe` file it open for a nano-second and close it without staying or showing me the hello world line.

Why?

Comment: that's  normal if you're running the .exe in a gui. when the program exits, the window closes. if the program doesn't pause before exiting, you don't get to see the window in the microsecond it's open. put a pause or prompt for input into your executable, or run it from a cmd window instead.

Comment: As stated by @MarcB, put a `raw_input()` at the end of your code and it'll wait for your input while showing your "Hello World" statement.

Comment: its work! thanks alot Dot_Py & Marc B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a `raw_input()` (or `input()` in python 3.x) at the end of your code; this way it'll wait for your input while showing your "Hello World" statement.

**Code:**

```
print "Hello World!"
end_command = raw_input("Press any key to exit...")
```

Comment: I've posted this as an answer because you should accept it, since it has provided a solution to your problem. By doing that, this question will be classified as "solved".

Comment: you should click on the "check" sign under the 0 points of this answer